# Android Image Masking with Rotate & Scale

Tags: android

How to mask image such as we can scale/zoom/rotate the background image but not the mask?

[image: mask]

I should be able to zoom the image in this mask but it is scaling whole image.

Suggest me a way to achieve this, I'm creating a photo collage app.

[image: collage]

Blue color is background of Layout.

The white color is for mask

I'm able to achieve this type of layout with masking, but when I apply MultiTouchListener to scale and zoom, it will scale the whole image with mask and not the image inside it.

```
private void getMaskedBitmap() {

    Bitmap bgBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background_drawable);
    ImageView bg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg);
    bg.setImageBitmap(bgBitmap);

    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
    Bitmap emptyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bgBitmap.getWidth(), bgBitmap.getHeight(), conf);
    Canvas canvasBmp = new Canvas(bgBitmap);


    ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.troll_face);

    Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.random_drawable);

    Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mask_drawable);

    original = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), true);

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    //mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_drawable);

    bg.setOnTouchListener(new MultiTouchListener());

    mImageView.invalidate();


}
```

Exception on line

> Canvas canvasBmp = new Canvas(bgBitmap);

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor**

Comment: put emptyBitmap in canvas instead of bgBitmap. Like Canvas canvasBmp = new Canvas(emptyBitmap );

Comment: @pokerface Do I need to create a custom view just in MainActivity?

Comment: your code doesn't look good.  Like you can use canvasBmp instead of mCanvas

Comment: Yes, create a custom view (could be custom imageView etc), and do all this stuff in onDraw.

Comment: @pokerface If I use canvasBmp then there is no background image inside.

Comment: @pokerface this.setOnTouchListener(new MultiTouchListener()); If I assign this it will scale whole view with mask, How to I assign it to only background image? Do I need to take new ImageView below it in RelativeLayout?

Comment: Draw any thing on canvasBmp, it will be drawn on empty bitmap, like you were drawing on mCanvas. Actually, my suggestion is, you should first see a complete working example of canvas and drawing so that you can understand what's going on

Comment: For example see this link http://www.techrepublic.com/article/punch-a-hole-in-a-bitmap-by-using-androids-porter-duff-xfer/

Comment: @pokerface I'm able to achieve the masking, now I don't know what to do?
What should I try to do next?

Comment: @pokerface I tried many thing, but not able to achieve this. Do you have any reference blog or code?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot provide you code but here is what you should do:

1. Get background image as bitmap and draw it on view's canvas.
2. Create an new (empty) bitmap of same size (use Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) and get its canvas, here you will draw mask.

   Canvas canvasBmp = new Canvas(bmp);
3. Now draw bmp on view's canvas. So, that you can get mask effect on image.
4. Zoom (re-size etc whatever you want) background bitmap image.
5. Invalidate your view, and follow all steps again

Comment: the masking image contains transparency, so that I can change background color. So there is no background image.

Comment: Is blue color image not the background ? And creating image with ARGB_8888 configuration you can achieve transparency

Comment: If your are using blue background as view's background then, try not to. Instead draw it on view's canvas

Comment: Blue color is background of LinearLayout, I want to add four different images in these four circles, and then I should able to rotate  the image which I've added to circle. I should also able to change the blue color with other color or texture. I think masking is only way to achieve these functions.

Comment: Regrading the solution, I'm trying the solution you suggested, I'm noob so it will take some time understand how this canvas and paint works.

Comment: I have tried to use your steps but it throws exception, I have edited my answer.